# SOAPUI - GZ file in Response

Tags: soapui, attachment, gzip, xop

I am using SOAPUI. It invokes a SOAP call, which downloads a gz file. The response includes a gz file. In the Attachments tab of the response, I do see a file abc.gz, with Content-type application/gzip, and Type XOP.

I have tried setting up the Request Properties - I have Enable MTOM as true. I have also specified a dump file.

The dump file is not a gzip file, but a XOP file

My question is - how do I extract just the gz file from this?

The XOP file looks like

```
--uuid:273aa462-94dc-405a-9972-82904edfb02e
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <root.message@cxf.apache.org>

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ns2:abcResponse xmlns:ns2="<url>"><return><xop:Include xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:1b73858f-12b5-4709-99d1-66974e55499c-22@cxf.apache.org"/></return></ns2:abcResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
--uuid:273aa462-94dc-405a-9972-82904edfb02e
Content-Type: application/gzip
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <1b73858f-12b5-4709-99d1-66974e55499c-22@cxf.apache.org>
Content-Disposition: attachment;name="abc.gz"

<binary data>
```

Comment: Afaik xop file is just an xml file with base64-encoded data in it. Could you try opening it through notepad check if this is true?

Comment: That is true. I just do not know how to extract the gzip part from it

Comment: If it is not too much to ask can you provide an exemplary xop file so that people(and I) have an idea what we are dealing with?